# vb.net xpath filter causing xslt error

Tags: vb.net, xpath

This code was working ok but I needed to filter on one of the nodes, I added the ends-wuth function.  now I am getting an error saying XSLT content is needed, I am unsure what is wrong.

```
Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
doc.Load("http://hatrafficinfo.dft.gov.uk/feeds/datex/England/CurrentRoadworks   /content.xml")
Dim nsmgr As New XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable)
nsmgr.AddNamespace("x", "http://datex2.eu/schema/1_0/1_0")

Dim nodeList As XmlNodeList = doc.SelectNodes("/x:d2LogicalModel/x:payloadPublication   /x:situation/x:situationRecord/x:groupOfLocations/x:locationContainedInGroup   /x:tpegpointLocation/x:*[ends-with(name(),'oint')]/x:pointCoordinates/x:latitude, nsmgr)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft´s XPath implementation only support XPath 1.0 and `ends-with` is new in XPath 2.0. If you want to use XPath 2.0 look for third party solutions like XmlPrime.

Your simple predicate could be written as `x:*[substring(name(), string-length(name()) - 3) = 'oint']`.